# Does a derived class automatically have all the attributes of the base class?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, attributes, derived

There seems to be no good online documentation on this:
If I make a derived class, will it automatically have all the attributes of the base class? But what's the `BaseClass.__init()` for, do you also need to do it to other base class methods? Does `BaseClass.__init__()` need arguments? If you have arguments for your base class `__init__()`, are they also used by the derived class, do you need to explicitly set the arguments to the derived classe's `__init__()`, or set them to `BaseClass.__init__()` instead?

Answer (score 62):

If you implement `__init__` in a class derived from BaseClass, then it will overwrite the inherited `__init__` method and so `BaseClass.__init__` will never be called. If you need to call the `__init__` method for BaseClass (as is normally the case), then its up to you to do that, and its done explicitly by calling `BaseClass.__init__`, normally from within the newly implemented `__init__` method.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def do_something(self):
        print self.a

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 20

bar = Bar()
bar.do_something()
```

This will cause the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'Bar' object has no attribute 'a'
```

So, the `do_something` method has been inherited as expected, but that method requires the attribute `a` to have been set, which it never is because `__init__` was also overwritten. We get round this by explicitly calling `Foo.__init__` from within `Bar.__init__`.

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 10

    def do_something(self):
        print self.a

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self)
        self.b = 20

bar = Bar()
bar.do_something()
```

which prints `10` as expected. `Foo.__init__` in this case expects a single argument which is an instance of `Foo` (which by convention is called `self`).

Normally, when you call a method on an instance of a class, the class instance is passed automatically as the first argument. Methods on an instance of a class are called *bound methods*. `bar.do_something` is an example of a bound method (and you'll note that it is called without any arguments). `Foo.__init__` is an *unbound method* because it is not attached to a particular instance of `Foo`, so the first argument, an instance of `Foo`, needs to be passed explicitly.

In our case, we pass `self` to `Foo.__init__`, which is the instance of `Bar` that was passed to the `__init__` method in `Bar`. Since `Bar` inherits from `Foo`, instances of `Bar` are also instances of `Foo`, so passing `self` to `Foo.__init__` is allowed.

It is likely be the case that the class you are inheriting from requires or accepts more arguments than just an instance of the class. These are dealt with as you would with any method you're calling from within `__init__`:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a=10):
        self.a = a

    def do_something(self):
        print self.a

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self):
        Foo.__init__(self, 20)

bar = Bar()
bar.do_something()
```

which would print `20`.

If you're trying to implement a interface that fully exposes all the initialisation arguments of the base class through your inheriting class, you'll need to do so explicitly. This is typically done with the *args and **kwargs arguments (the names are by convention), which are placeholders for all rest of the arguments that aren't explicitly named. The following example makes use of everything I've discussed:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b=10):
        self.num = a * b

    def do_something(self):
        print self.num

class Bar(Foo):
    def __init__(self, c=20, *args, **kwargs):
        Foo.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.c = c

    def do_something(self):
        Foo.do_something(self)
        print self.c


bar = Bar(40, a=15)
bar.do_something()
```

In this case, the argument `c` is set to be 40, as it's the first argument to `Bar.__init__`. The second argument is then incorporated into the variables `args` and `kwargs` (the * and ** is specific syntax that says expand the list/tuple or dictionary into separate arguments when passing to a function/method), and is passed on to `Foo.__init__`.

This example also makes the point that *any* overwritten method needs to be called explicitly if that is what is required (as `do_something` is in this case).

One final point, you will often see `super(ChildClass, self).method()` (where `ChildClass` is some arbitrary child class) being used instead of a call to the `BaseClass` method explicitly. Discussion of `super` is a whole other question, but suffice it to say, in these cases it's typically being used to do exactly what is being done by calling `BaseClass.method(self)`. Briefly, `super` delegates the method call to the next class in the method resolution order - the MRO (which in single inheritance is the parent class). See the [documentation on super](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#super) for more info.

Comment: @PM2Ring where do you mean?

Comment: @PM2Ring No, that's the point. `Bar` extends `Foo` with the `c` attribute. `Foo` can't take a keyword `c`. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I was a little confused (and I couldn't easily test it on my phone).

Answer (score 11):

> If I make a derived class, will it automatically have all the attributes of the base class?

Class attributes, yes. Instance attributes, no (simply because they don't exist when the class is created), unless there's no `__init__` in the derived class, in which case the base one will be called instead, and will set the instance attributes.

> Does BaseClass.**init**() need arguments?

Depends on the class and its `__init__` signature. If you're explicitly calling `Base.__init__` in the derived class, you will at least need to pass `self` as the first argument. If you have

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # something
```

then it's rather obvious that no other arguments are accepted by the `__init__`. If you'd have

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, argument):
        # something
```

then you have to pass `argument` when calling base `__init__`. No rocket science in here.

> If you have arguments for your base class **init**(), are they also used by the derived class, do you need to explicitly set the arguments to the derived classe's **init**(), or set them to BaseClass.**init**() instead?

Again, if the derived class doesn't have `__init__`, base one will be used instead.

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print 'Base'

class Derived(Base):
    pass

Derived()   # TypeError
Derived(42) # prints Base
```

In other case, you need to take care of it somehow. Whether you use `*args, **kwargs` and just pass arguments unmodified to the base class, or copy the base class signature, or supply arguments from elsewhere, depends on what you're trying to accomplish.