# Boost::python wrapper for derived class method

Tags: python, boost, wrapper, derived

I have C++ class and its wrapper for boost::python:

```cpp
class CApp
{
 public:
   virtual bool FOOs (){}; //does not matter for now
   bool Run( const char * First,const char * Last) 
   {
     ...
     return "Running..."
   };

struct pyApp : CApp, wrapper<CApp>  //derived class 
{
   ... // wrappers for virtual methods
}

#include <boost/python.hpp>
using namespace boost::python;
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE( myApp )
{
class_<pyApp, boost::noncopyable>("CApp", init<>()   )
            ...
    .def("Run",&pyMOOSApp::Run);
}
```

Compiling is OK. But when i'm invoking Python code

```py
from myApp import *

class pyApp(CApp):
def __init__(self):
    print "INIT-->"

CClass = CApp()
pyClass = pyApp()
CClass.Run('myApp','bar')
pyClass.Run('myApp','bar')
```

I have an error:

```
INIT-->
Running... // this is from CClass.Run
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./pytest.py", line 18, in <module>
pyClass.Run('myApp','bar')
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
CApp.Run(pyApp, str, str)
did not match C++ signature:
Run(CApp {lvalue}, char const*, char const*)
```

So I've tries to write a wrapper for Run method that is converting str to char placed in derived class c++ code:

```cpp
bool Run(std::string a, std::string b) {
    char * cstrA;
    char * cstrB;
    cstrA = new char[a.size()+1];
    cstrB = new char[b.size()+1];
    strcpy(cstrA,a.c_str());
    strcpy(cstrB,b.c_str());
    return this -> CApp::Run(cstrA, cstrB);
}
```

But the only change was in the last stroke:

```
did not match C++ signature:
Run(pyApp {lvalue}, std::string, std::string)
```

**I'm pretty sure that a have bad wrapper for the Run method**, so any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw your other question ([Using derived class (C++) by Python BOOST](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14076708/82896)) and believe this has the same solution. You need to call init() on the base class if you provide an init in the derived class. See my solution here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14742937/82896.