# Is the derived class an instance of the base class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object, inheritance

When we create a new derived class is it considered as an instance of the base class?
the derived class will have all the functions and attribute that any instance of the base class have.

Comment: Inheritance means IS-A.  The Liskov Substitution principle means a child B can be used anywhere a parent A is required.

Comment: The derived class itself is not an instance of its base class. Instances of the derived class are instances of the base class.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396452/python-derived-class-and-base-class-attributes#6396839

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- The derived class is usually called a *subclass* of the base class(es).
- Instances of the derived class are also instances of the base class(es).
- The derived class is not an instance of the base class, but it is an instance of the base class [*metaclass*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-metaclass), unless the derived class overrides the metaclass.